# Are not all Emmet actions available in WebStorm?

Tags: html, webstorm, emmet

I have Emmet enabled for WebStorm but it seems as though some of the abbreviations aren't working.

For example: typing `div` and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (I have the abbreviation key set to Enter) will open a `<div>` tag as expected. However, actions like these are not working:

`!` should open up the html boilerplate. Instead, it doesn't do anything.

`form:get` should open up `<form action="" method="get"></form>` Instead, it opens up `<form:get></form:get>`.

I even tested on other JetBrains products like IntelliJ and Android Studio using the same settings and they both work as expected.

Any ideas?

Screenshots:

Emmet HTML settings:
[image: Emmet HTML settings]

Emmet abbreviation:
[image: Emmet abbreviation]

Zen HTML settings:
[image: Zen HTML settings]

Comment: Show your settings: screenshots of the Emmet settings (the key used) as well as what you have for `!` entry (it is implemented using standard Live Template functionality, will be under "Zen HTML" node). It works fine here in PhpStorm 2020.3.1, tested in a plain .html file. There has to be something that you may be doing differently or different settings.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down my problem. I had imported settings for some React snippets (https://github.com/ifahrentholz/webstorm-snippets) that must have overridden some of the Emmet Abbreviations.